# How to fix the size of an element across devices

Tags: css

I want an element which is of a fixed size from the perspective of reality - say 6 x 3 cm - for whoever is viewing it. So I've set it to 400 X 200 px - and then change my layout around this element (single column display for smaller displays etc.)

This works fine when I change the size of my desktop browser - the element appears the same, but the layout changes - but when I open dev tools and simulate mobile devices, the element appears far smaller.

Is there any easy way to fix the (real world) size of the element across devices?

I'm really stuck on this (I'm sure very simple) point, so any help would be much appreciated!

For example:

[This is what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLnpC.png)

Comment: where's your css and html

Comment: paste your code here whatever you'd tried

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to stack overflow. When asking a question on here, it's usually a good idea to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. In your question you could create a code snippet using the icon that looks like a page with some angle brackets on. Good luck!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT / CHANGED ANSWER (after seeing the image you added):

As a first step, put this into the `<head>`tag of your HTML code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The page will not be zoomed down to the size of the viewport (i.e. mobile screen) anymore if you add that.

Then read about how to use media queries...

Comment: There appears to be the same effect when I use cm.

Comment: Thanks! That was it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css

```
@media(max-width:480px){
  .test{
     width:100%; /*as per your requirement*/
     height:500px;
  }
```

}

NOTE: this one is for specific device with maximum with 480px, you can add other size too the similar way. And don't forget to change the value of `width` & `height` as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks - I added the rule, but it didn't seem to make any difference?

Comment: it suppose to be `@media(max-width:480px)` not `480`. did you change that to. remember you also need to include the `viewport` meta tag like Johannes mentioned

Comment: Ah yes, that was what I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to get this behavior:

1. learn how to write your own media query
   http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
2. use a framework like bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/ and manage visibility classes

> ```
> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block visible-xs">My button</button>
> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">My button</button>
> ```

Comment: The behaviour is different depending on the device, not just the size of the viewport - I have a basic understanding of what media queries are, but I'm not sure how to write them in this case

Comment: What do you mean with "behavior"?

Comment: The size (appearance) of the div being displayed

Comment: The size of the DIV ? If you set your size in % your page will be responsive, in your sample you're setting height and width in px, and what you're obtaining is the result of this choice
I suggest you to take a look to a responsive framework like as bootstrap